# Google Play: set introductory offer for a subset of countries

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have a monthly subscription setup in Google Play (say for $2.99/month) with default exchange rates for all other currencies.

I want to create an introductory price of $1.99 for only ONE country. So I create an introductory price with the same $2.99/mo price and manually override to a lower price for that one country.

When I try to save I get an error for most currencies:

> Introductory price for `country` must be within the accepted price range and less than the subscription's full price

I get it, I'm not giving a lower price for most countries. Is there a way to do this in the Google Play console? In App Store Connect (Apple) it's easy to set it per-country.